# Prove this trigonometric identity?

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $(\tan^2 \theta -\sin^2 \theta) = (\tan^2 \theta) \cdot (\sin^2 \theta)$

Comment: Hint: $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ and recall the [Pythagorean identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity).

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\tan^2 \theta \times \sin^2 \theta \quad&=\dfrac{\sin^2 \theta}{cos^2 \theta} \times \sin^2 \theta\\&= \dfrac{(1-\cos^2 \theta)\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}\\&= \dfrac{\sin^2 \theta-\sin^2 \theta\cos^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}\\&=\dfrac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}-\sin^2 \theta\\&= \tan^2 \theta-\sin^2 \theta\end{align}$$